# Can't import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

I've been following Burt Beckwith's tutorial on Spring Security for Grails 3.  I installed the plugin build.gradle as it said in the tutorial, and ran s2-quickstart, which seems to work fine.  The project compiles without complaint.

However when I try the import statement

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
```

the import isn't recognized and won't build, with error

```
Error:(2, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
```

What's missing?

dependencies section of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'  //*** 
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
```

Comment: Try to clean and compile your project.

Comment: Also it helps to force Gradle to update the dependencies in your IDE or via `gradle --refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: Unless im missing something it looks like refresh-dependencies was dropped from grails 3 but seems like same result from clea then compile

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve this issue in IntelliJ by clicking the "refresh" icon in the View \ Tools \ Gradle window.